# Python Check if two list of jsons are equal

Tags: python, json

I have two list of JSON objects:

```
[{u'amount': 12000, u'address': u'mqdofsXHpePPGBFXuwwypAqCcXi48Xhb2f'},
 {u'amount': 1000, u'address': u'mkVuZV2kVtMzddQabFDanFi6DTwWYtgiCn'}]

[{"amount": 12000, "address": "mqdofsXHpePPGBFXuwwypAqCcXi48Xhb2f"},
 {"amount": 1000, "address": "mkVuZV2kVtMzddQabFDanFi6DTwWYtgiCn"}]
```

They might come in different orders, or one might be a subset of the other or just different addresses, I need a function to just say True if both include the same **addresses/amounts** or False if they are different.

I guess the problem is one has unicode keys/values but the other ones are strings.

I've spent too much time on this simple issue that have no clue what else to do.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, it looks like the Python dict literal syntax.

Comment: I printed them out for logging with ("%s  - %s" % (outputs, new_outputs))

Comment: Do the "amount" entries matter?

Comment: @Asad yes, the pair matters. even if you swap the amounts for each addresses it should return False

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611854/checking-if-two-massive-python-dictionaries-are-equivalent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-in-python http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_cmp.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in the end this is what I wrote, might not be the most efficient way but it works!

```
def json_equal(json1,json2):

   number_of_items = len(json1)
   for item in json1:
       for item2 in json2:
           if item["address"] == item2["address"]:
               if item["amount"] == item2["amount"]:
                   number_of_items -= 1
                   break
           else:
               continue
   if number_of_items == 0:
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to use a data structure that ignores the order in which elements appear when performing an equality comparison - say, a `set`. Try this, which uses set comprehensions for extracting the addresses and amounts from each list:

```
{(d['address'], d['amount']) for d in lst1} == {(d['address'], d['amount']) for d in lst2}
```

Comment: the key value should be the same to be True, both address and the amount.

Comment: anyhow I'd try a nested if

Comment: @Shayanbahal You can just concatenate the address and amount and compare.

Comment: @Shayanbahal {(json['address'], json['amount']) for json in lst1} == {(json['address'], json['amount']) for json in lst2}