# Unordered hash in Python

Tags: python, hash

I'd like to compare the dicts by content, so I thought this can be done by creating an unordered hash of the item tuples.

What is the most elegant solution for that?

I was thinking about XORing all individual hashes, but maybe there is another ready-made solution?

EDIT:
I have *nested* data structures. Some classes contain dicts. These classes can be aggregated to sets. So to compare the sets with the predefined set comparison I have to implement both `__eq__` (which is easy) and `__hash__` (which is my question) for my dict-classes?!

Comment: I do not follow what you are trying to do. Could you give us some examples of comparisons you want to make?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165352/fast-comparison-between-two-python-dictionary ?

Comment: Are your classes immutable? `set` assumes the hash values of the elements do not change.

Comment: @JanneKarila: Hmm, they aren't exactly immutable, but I only need the set comparison momentarily to compare an unordered set of my classes.

Answer (score 2):

To check that all values are the same for overlapping keys, one of the following (depending on Python version) and style:

```
if all(dict_a[key] == dict_b[key] for key in dict_a.viewkeys() & dict_b.viewkeys())
```

---

```
if all(dict_a[key] == dict_b[key] for key in set(dict_a) & set(dict_b))
```

---

To handle the "are they the same value" a bit more specifically...

```
for k, v in dict_a.iteritems():
    try:
        ov = dict_b[k]
    except KeyError as e:
        continue
    if v == ov: 
        pass # or whatever
```

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That's what is being used in the 2nd example - the first example is taking advantage of the `dict_keys` object (which can behave set-ish ) returned by `.viewkeys()` - so not quite sure what your comment means?

Answer (score 0):

See  [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for Mapping Type..
You have already got operators defined to do various operations on Dictionary..