# Print diff of Python dictionaries

Tags: python

I want to take two dictionaries and print a diff of them.  This diff should include the differences in keys AND values.  I've created this little snippet to achieve the results using built-in code in the `unittest` module.  However, it's a nasty hack since I have to subclass `unittest.TestCase` and provide a `runtest()` method for it to work.  In addition, this code will cause the application to error out since it will raise an `AssertError` when there are differences.  All I really want is to print the diff.

```
import unittest
class tmp(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
         # Show full diff of objects (dicts could be HUGE and output truncated)
        self.maxDiff = None
    def runTest():
        pass
_ = tmp()
_.assertDictEqual(d1, d2)
```

I was hoping to use the `difflib` module, but it looks to only work for strings.  Is there some way to work around this and still use `difflib`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165352/fast-comparison-between-two-python-dictionary

Comment: @MarkReed -- This is different.  That asked for the differences in *keys*, this asks for the difference in *keys* and *values* (I assume the OP needs *key-value* pairs) -- e.g. `{1:2, 2:3}` is different from `{1:3,2:2}`, but that's not actually explicitly stated...

Comment: @mgilson - I didn't put in a close request or mark this as a duplicate, but if you look at the accepted answer on that page, it includes value comparison, not just keyset comparison.

Comment: I don't necessarily mind this solution.  However, is there a way to clean it up a bit?  Two things I would want to change: 1. Catch/suppress AssertError (easy to do but seems weird) 2. Use `assertDictEqual` without having to subclass `TestCase`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use difflib, but the use unittest method seems more appropriate to me. But if you wanted to use difflib. Let's say say the following are the two dicts.

```
In [50]: dict1
Out[50]: {1: True, 2: False}

In [51]: dict2
Out[51]: {1: False, 2: True}
```

You may need to convert them to strings (or list of strings) and then go about using difflib as a normal business.

```
In [43]: a = '\n'.join(['%s:%s' % (key, value) for (key, value) in sorted(dict1.items())])
In [44]: b = '\n'.join(['%s:%s' % (key, value) for (key, value) in sorted(dict2.items())])
In [45]: print a
1:True
2:False
In [46]: print b
1:False
2:True
In [47]: for diffs in difflib.unified_diff(a.splitlines(), b.splitlines(), fromfile='dict1', tofile='dict2'):
    print diffs
```

THe output would be:

```
--- dict1

+++ dict2

@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@

-1:True
-2:False
+1:False
+2:True
```

Comment: This looks pretty cool.  Good idea.  Why would you say the unittest method is more appropriate here?

Comment: @durden2.0 unittest method seems to provide an easier way to do. no translating to string required, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Adapted from the cpython source:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/01fd68752e2d2d0a5f90ae8944ca35df0a5ddeaa/Lib/unittest/case.py#L1091

```
import difflib
import pprint

def compare_dicts(d1, d2):
    return ('\n' + '\n'.join(difflib.ndiff(
                   pprint.pformat(d1).splitlines(),
                   pprint.pformat(d2).splitlines())))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.items()` along with sets to do something like this:

```
>>> d = dict((i,i) for i in range(10))
>>> d2 = dict((i,i) for i in range(1,11))
>>>
>>> set(d.items()) - set(d2.items())
set([(0, 0)])
>>>
>>> set(d2.items()) - set(d.items())
set([(10, 10)])
>>>
>>> set(d2.items()) ^ set(d.items())  #symmetric difference
set([(0, 0), (10, 10)])
>>> set(d2.items()).symmetric_difference(d.items())  #only need to actually create 1 set
set([(0, 0), (10, 10)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a library (not very well documented) called [datadiff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datadiff/1.1.4) which gives out the diffs of hashable data structures in python. you can install it with pip or easy_install. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

See [Python recipe to create difference (as dictionary) of two dictionaries](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576644-diff-two-dictionaries/). Could you describe what the output should looks like (please attach an example)?

Comment: I'm not really set on a printing format.  I guess something that looks like standard unidiff would be nice.  However, the printing of assertDiffEqual() is not bad.  Here are some examples:AssertionError: {'a': 'a'} != {'a': 'abc'}
- {'a': 'a'}
+ {'a': 'abc'}
?         ++
AssertionError: {'a': 1} != {'a': 2}
- {'a': 1}
?       ^

+ {'a': 2}
?       ^

Answer (score 0):

using @[mgilson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957021/1561176) and taking it  a step further for the OP's request to work with `unittest` module.

```
def test_dict_diff(self):
    dict_diff = list(set(self.dict_A.items()).symmetric_difference(set(self.dict_B.items()))))
    fail_message = "too many differences:\nThe differences:\n" +
                   "%s" % "\n".join(dict_diff)
    self.assertTrue((len(dict_diff) < self.maxDiff), fail_message)
```

Comment: This is pretty neat, but I think using the built-in `assertDictEqual()` is a better solution if the code is already using the `unittest` module.

Comment: `assertDictEqual` is in 2.7+ i use 2.6 ... and so i assume everyone does. :P but yes, that would be better to use.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/inveniosoftware/dictdiffer

```
print list(diff(
    {2014: [
        dict(month=6, category=None, sum=672.00),
        dict(month=6, category=1, sum=-8954.00),
        dict(month=7, category=None, sum=7475.17),
        dict(month=7, category=1, sum=-11745.00),
        dict(month=8, category=None, sum=-12140.00),
        dict(month=8, category=1, sum=-11812.00),
        dict(month=9, category=None, sum=-31719.41),
        dict(month=9, category=1, sum=-11663.00),
    ]},

    {2014: [
       dict(month=6, category=None, sum=672.00),
       dict(month=6, category=1, sum=-8954.00),
       dict(month=7, category=None, sum=7475.17),
       dict(month=7, category=1, sum=-11745.00),
       dict(month=8, category=None, sum=-12141.00),
       dict(month=8, category=1, sum=-11812.00),
       dict(month=9, category=None, sum=-31719.41),
       dict(month=9, category=1, sum=-11663.00),
    ]}))
```

gives this output which I think is pretty great:

```
[('change', ['2014', 4, 'sum'], (-12140.0, -12141.0))]
```

i.e. it gives what happened: a value "changed", the path "['2014', 4, 'sum']" and that it changed from -12140.0 to -12141.0.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a string and a flattened dictionary with the differences between the dictionaries

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
import pandas as pd
def get_dict_value_differences(current_dict, past_dict):
    """
    find the added keys and different values between the dictionaries
    :param current_dict:
    :param past_dict:
    :return: flattened dictionary of changed values
    """
    current_flat_dict = flatten_dict(current_dict)
    past_flat_dict = flatten_dict(past_dict)

    flat_diff_dict = dict()
    for key, value in current_flat_dict.items():
        if key in current_flat_dict.keys() and key in past_flat_dict.keys():
            if current_flat_dict[key] != past_flat_dict[key]:
                flat_diff_dict[key] = current_flat_dict[key]
        elif key in current_flat_dict.keys():
            flat_diff_dict[key] = current_flat_dict[key]

    diff_str = str(*[str(k) + ':' + str(v) for k, v in flat_diff_dict.items()])
    return flat_diff_dict, diff_str


def flatten_dict(d: MutableMapping, sep: str= '.') -> MutableMapping:
    [flat_dict] = pd.json_normalize(d, sep=sep).to_dict(orient='records')
    return flat_dict
```