# Comparing dictionaries by corresponding keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm quite the beginner in Python.

I have two dictionaries, where each key is a product and each value is the price to each product.

```
productData_1 = {'product_1': '18', 'product_2': '15', 'product_3': '10', 'product_4': '9'}
productData_2 = {'product_1': '18', 'product_3': '12', 'product_2': '15'}
```

What I want to do is compare both dictionaries both by keys and by values, so that I can see the differences between both dicts, e.g. are there different prices, is a product missing in `productData_1` or `_2`?

I know that I have to iterate over both dicts in some way but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: You'll have to define more clearly what your desired output is. In your post you have multiple questions: do you want as result "product_4" (because it's the only one not in both dicts) or "product_3" (because its value is different in the two dicts), or a combination of both?

Comment: Yes, this question is very likely a duplicate. You should definitely check out the link giosans left in a comment above mine, and decide whether or not to delete this question. There are tons of questions already on StackOverflow about iterating over python dictionaries.

Comment: The top answer in this post includes a full solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165352/calculate-difference-in-keys-contained-in-two-python-dictionaries

Comment: You're right Chris, hadn't seen that.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.5:

```
productData_1 = {'product_1': '18', 'product_2': '15', 'product_3': '10', 'product_4': '9'}
productData_2 = {'product_1': '18', 'product_3': '12', 'product_2': '15'}

keys = set (productData_1.keys () + productData_2.keys ())

for key in keys:
    try:
        if productData_1 [key] != productData_2 [key]:
            print ('Mismatch at key {}'.format (key))
    except:
        print ('Entry missing at key {}'.format (key))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in productData_1.keys()|productData_2.keys():
    if key not in productData_1:
        print('{} missing from productData_1!'.format(key))
        continue
    if key not in productData_2:
        print('{} missing from productData_2!'.format(key))
        continue
    print('Difference in prices for key "{}": {}'.format(key,abs(int(productData_1[key])-int(productData_2[key]))))
```

This code will print if a key is missing from either dict and print the absolute difference between values for each key.

`productData_1.keys()|productData_2.keys()` will return the union of dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
keys_unique_to_1 = [key for key in productData_1 if key not in productData_2]
keys_unique_to_2 = [key for key in productData_2 if key not in productData_1]
common_keys = [key for key in productData_1 if key in productData_2]

diff = {key: int(productData_1[key]) - int(productData_2[key]) for key in common_keys}

print 'Keys unique to 1: ', keys_unique_to_1
# Keys unique to 1:  ['product_4']

print 'Keys unique to 2: ', keys_unique_to_2
# Keys unique to 2:  []

print 'Difference: ', diff
# Difference:  {'product_1': 0, 'product_3': -2, 'product_2': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python) on this issue. You can loop through both your dictionaries and compare their values. The example hereunder shows how you can print the keys for which your values are equal.

=========================================================================

productData_1 = {'product_1': '18', 'product_2': '15', 'product_3': '10', 'product_4': '9'}
productData_2 = {'product_1': '18', 'product_3': '12', 'product_2': '15'}

**For Python 2.x-**

```
for key_1, value_1 in productData_1.iteritems():
    for key_2, value_2 in productData_2.iteritems():
    if value_1 == value_2:
         print("key_1" + str(key_1))
         print("key_2" + str(key_2))
```

**For Python 3.x-**

```
for key_1, value_1 in productData_1.items():
     for key_2, value_2 in productData_2.items():
     if value_1 == value_2:
         print("key_1" + str(key_1))
         print("key_2" + str(key_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
productData_1 = {'product_1': '18', 'product_2': '15', 'product_3': '10', 'product_4': '9'}
productData_2 = {'product_1': '18', 'product_3': '12', 'product_2': '15'}

matched_keys = []
unmatched_keys = []
matched_value = []
unmatched_value = []

for ind,value in productData_1.items():
    if ind in productData_2.keys():
        matched_keys.append( ind )
        if value in productData_2.values():
            matched_value.append( value )
        else:
            unmatched_value.append( value )
    else:
        unmatched_keys.append( ind )
        if value in productData_2.values():
            matched_value.append( value )
        else:
            unmatched_value.append( value )



print matched_keys
print unmatched_keys

print matched_value
print unmatched_value
```